# Length of class object

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

I have an array `AAA *aaa[len]`, where `AAA` is a class.

```
class AAA
{...};

int main()
{
   cin >> len;
   AAA *aaa[len]; // how to get the length of aaa?
}
```

How to get the length of `aaa`? I tried `sizeof(aaa)/sizeof(AAA)` but it is wrong.
Obviously, the length of `aaa` is `len`, but I want to obtain the length by other methods.

Comment: `sizeof(aaa)/sizeof(aaa[0])` or `sizeof(aaa)/sizeof(AAA*)`. The type of the array element is not `AAA`, but `AAA*`; you've declared an array of pointers.

Comment: You don't. This is not valid C++, but non-standard C++.

Comment: It would be prudent to add that [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not valid in standard C++. Some compilers (including yours, apparently) accept them as an extension, but be aware that your program is not portable.